# How do I track window size with jquery?

Tags: jquery, resize, dropdown

I want to make a dropdown, drop down on hover, but only when the screen size is larger than 767px. I managed to do this by putting in a resize function like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 767) {
   // MAKE THE DROPDOWN WORK
  }
});
```

Except this doesnt work at all. Or it does but not how I want it to. I want jquery to track the screen size all the time. What happens is if I resize the window and its higher than 767px then the dropdown always works. How do I make jquery track what screen size the window is at all times?

Basically I need it to work like a css media query.

Comment: This is tracked at all times. From the description I assume that you instead mean that you want to also run this logic when the page loads. As such, add `.trigger('resize')` to the end of what you have now

Comment: or just call `$(window).resize()` after your function to initially trigger the event

Comment: Use `$(window).innerWidth()` instead of `$(window).width()`.